# How does the "Fully Loaded" ace work?

Tags: payday-2

The description for the "Fully Loaded" perk says "Enemies drop 75% more ammunition".

Does that mean:

- If my buddy, who has the Fully Loaded perk, kills someone, I can get 75% more ammo by picking up his drops?
- The player with the perk picks up 75% more ammo than they ordinarily would when picking up ammo drops, but there is no effect for me, if I don't have the perk?

Comment: Perks like effect the entire team.  Its doubtful this effect stacks though.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of the person with the perk **picking up ammo** not who ever kills the enemy as the wording suggests. If you have Fully Loaded Aced one "ammo pack" you pick up on the ground has 75% more ammo in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume from my experience that it would only work for you/the person with the perk.